# Blurred fonts for all labels in the iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad, antialiasing, label

We have been developing an iPad app and we are seeing one strange issue.

Once we deploy app on device , in some of the iPads we see that fonts of all the labels are coming as blurred (fonts are visible but are faded/blurred).

In some iPads, we can see the issue but couldn't see the issue on all the iPads.
It is not os specific (seen on both ios5 and ios6) . Issue doesn't go even after killing app or reinstalling it.

If device show issue , it will always be there and if device doesn't show issue, it won't show it ever.

Any input on when this can happen or anyone has seen it before ?

Comment: Can you give us some more details about how you are using fonts? Any frameworks involved? Are you using a HD version of your fonts? Is your app supporting Retina displays?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the problem can be that the coordinates are not integers.
You can Fix it with `CGRectIntegral()`.
Sample:

```
subView.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake( 0, 0, sizeWidth, sizeHeight));
```

Comment: This was my immediate thought, but +1 for the function I didn't know about!

Answer (score -1):

It depends on iPad version. Seems you can see blurry labels only on iPad 2 ( non retina display ). And it not depends on iOS version. Rounding frame and center will fix it